# Close Activities that are opened in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have created an android program which has 5 activities?

1. Main activity from there I get into Login activity
2. Login activity to Activity A
3. Activity A to Activity B
4. Activity B to C Activity or D Activity
5. C Activity or D Activity to Main Activity

I know I have to put a finish() for all the activity but the problem is that I don't want put a finish() before all new activities instead is there way to finish all running activities in main screen by a click of a button along with main screen activity?

Comment: I think what you have asked, has been already asked many times:
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=finish+all+activities+android

Comment: I don't think these are what I am looking for... I want to finish all the activities along with main activity.

Comment: You don't want the backstack, right? Open your last `activity` with this intent flags: `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` or `Intent.FLAG_NO_HISTORY`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use

android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

This will close your application

Comment: No, just no. Don't kill processes. There are several better ways.

Comment: Apps should not be killed by the user/developer, android is supposed to handle when an app should be closed. Using ``finish();`` for each activity should be fine. If you don't want the activity in the history use the FLAG_NO_HISTORY flag when starting the new intent

Comment: Finish() will not work in my case because I want to use back in couple of screens inside.

Comment: @user1443051 Thats why i asked you to try killProcess(). That will kill the application and from what you said I inferred that you wanted to close the application on press of a button. That is what killProcess() does